# Jquery Chosen and asp Listbox get multiple values on jquery 1.11.1 and chosen 1.4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I use `jquery 1.11.1` and chosen `1.4.2` for multiple choice

```
$("#<%=ddlOrg.ClientID %>").change(function() {
     $("#<%=ddlOrgResult.ClientID %>").val($(this).val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("org_unit_mast_Code")));
 });
```

the returns always `[ object object ]`  . it works when i user `jquery 1.4.1`  but when i change to `jquery 1.11.1` the result become `[object object]`  . why and how can i solve this?

i use 
     
ASP Listbox

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ddlOrg" SelectionMode="Multiple" data-placeholder="Pilih …" multiple class="chosen-select" DataSourceID="odsOrgUnit" DataValueField="org_unit_mast_Code" DataTextField="org_unit_mast_Name" runat="server" ></asp:ListBox>
```

i get this result on console

```
[select#MainContent_ddlOrg.chosen-select, input#MainContent_ddlOrgArray, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document] 0: select#MainContent_ddlOrg.chosen-select 1: input#MainContent_ddlOrgArray context: document length: 2 prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1] proto: jQuery[0]
```

i need the result as 'Value1, Value2, Value3' is there any way to get this result?

---

it SOLVED now.. i change the code into this

```
  var foo = [];
                      $(this).find("option:selected").each(function (i, selected) {
                          foo[i] = $(selected).val;
                      });

                      console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` method gets/sets the `.value` property of a DOM element. The `.value` can only be a string, a `DOMString`. Since you are passing a jQuery object to the method, the value is converted into a string. `[object Object]` is the string representation of the passed jQuery object. Which jQuery object? The returned object of the `val` method call as a *setter*: `.val($(this).val(...))`

It seems you want to modify the `value` property of 2 elements at the same time. For doing this you should either use the `val` method 2 times or use the jQuery `add` method for creating a collection of 2 elements.

```
$("#<%=ddlOrg.ClientID %>").change(function() {
   var attr = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("org_unit_mast_Code");
   $("#<%=ddlOrgArray.ClientID %>").add(this).val(attr);
});
```

Comment: still doesnt work.. i got this on console  [select#MainContent_ddlOrg.chosen-select, input#MainContent_ddlOrgArray, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document]
0: select#MainContent_ddlOrg.chosen-select
1: input#MainContent_ddlOrgArray
context: document
length: 2
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]
__proto__: jQuery[0]

Comment: i use asp i dont think i can run it on jsfiddle.. i use <asp:ListBox  ID="ddlOrg" SelectionMode="Multiple" data-placeholder="Pilih …" multiple class="chosen-select" DataSourceID="odsOrgUnit" 
                                        DataValueField="org_unit_mast_Code"  DataTextField="org_unit_mast_Name"  runat="server" ></asp:ListBox>  i need the result as 'Value1, Value2, Value3' is there any way to get this result?

Comment: i change the code into this

  var foo = [];
                      $(this).find("option:selected").each(function (i, selected) {
                          foo[i] = $(selected).attr("org_unit_mast_Code");
                      });

                      console.log(foo);
i got the result : [ undefined, undefined ]

Comment: ah... solved... i change into this  var foo = [];
                      $(this).find("option:selected").each(function (i, selected) {
                          foo[i] = $(selected).val();
                      });

Comment: @user1851384 I'm glad that you have solved the problem! For doing this you should select an answer. There is a check mark on the left side the answers. If you think that my answer hasn't helped you to solve the problem you can post an answer yourself and mark it as the correct answer.